# using Source() in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a working R application that I want to make available online using Shiny. My application receives a file as input, so the client uploads the file through ui.R. server.R receives the file and then I want to call my app. However, when I use source(), myApp does not know the file that I have received in the server.R and throws *error : object not found*. This is the code for server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$contents <- renderTable({
   inFile <- input$file1
   if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
   else{
      tdata <- as.matrix(read.table(inFile$datapath))
      head(tdata, n = 2)
      source("./CODE/run_myApp.r")
   }
  })
})
```

However, myApp doesn't include `tdata` (which is needed as the input file in my current app).

Comment: Try using `source("./CODE/run_myApp.r", local = TRUE)`

Comment: You need to `isolate` this part. `isolate({source("./CODE/run_myApp.r")})`

Comment: @Elahehkamaliha could you please mark the answer from jdharrison below as an answer?

Answer (score 32):

To use source in your shiny app you need to invoke the `local = TRUE` argument so in this case:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$contents <- renderTable({
   inFile <- input$file1
   if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
   else{
      tdata <- as.matrix(   read.table(inFile$datapath))
      head(tdata, n = 2)
      source("./CODE/run_myApp.r", local = TRUE)
   }
  })
})
```