# R - source()'ing files in Shiny UI Layer

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to take my Shiny apps and break them into smaller files to make collaborating via git with coworkers much easier.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864611/using-source-in-shiny) helped me figure out how to `source()` in files to my server.r by using `source(...,local=T)`.  Now I'm trying to do the same thing with my UI layer.

Consider this toy Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  plotOutput("test"),
  numericInput("n","Number of points",value=100,min=1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test = renderPlot({
    x = rnorm(input$n)
    y = rnorm(input$n)
    plot(y~x)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This app does what you would expect, one overly-wide graph of 100 random data points.  Now, what if I want to move just the `plotOutput` to a separate file (the real use case is in moving whole tabs of UI to separate files).  I make a new file called **tmp.R** and it has:

```
column(12,plotOutput("test"),numericInput("n","Number of points",value=100,min=1))
```

The reason for wrapping it in the `column` statement is because the comma's can't just be hanging out.  Now I update my UI to:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  source("tmp.R",local=T)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test = renderPlot({
    x = rnorm(input$n)
    y = rnorm(input$n)
    plot(y~x)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now, the word "TRUE" is just hanging out at the bottom of the page.[image: Snippet example of problem]

How do I eliminate this word from showing up?  Why is it there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `source("tmp.R",local = TRUE)$value` maybe

Comment: I would give you a thousand upvotes if I could.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @DeanAttali, appreciate if you could help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129562/in-r-shiny-how-to-fix-error-in-sourcing-app-as-nothing-changes-when-clicking-on