# when calling R script form Shiny - does the script can have just code?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have gone through this but it does not answer the question.
[using Source() in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864611/using-source-in-shiny)

I have a land use model in R Script that reads file from one input folder and does a lot of processing and generate outputs. Purpose of shiny is to modify inputs by increasing them by some percentage.  My question is, if the model is not packed like a function and as just plain code, would it be able to run and give out required output. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your R Script needs to:

1. Be called (with `source()`) inside the server of your Shiny App.
2. Use the `input$*` for the inputs you need to modify.

Having both, there shouldn't be a problem for it to work. But, yes, converting your R Script to a function then sourcing it before the code for the UI would be much better and understandable. Even for you in the future.